# jquery updating java hashmap on every request by user

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

Is it necessary to have data on the browser first and than update using jquery . Can't we direclty update the java objects in servlet . Please suggest , i have explained my scenerio here. Thanks !

In jsp i have written a jquery code which will send the get request to my Java servlet. Here is the jquery code .

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=portalContext.createTemplateProcessURI()%>' + '?s1=' + $("#networkBox1").val() + '&box1=Box1&tick=add&val1=' + allvs + '&s2=' + $("#networkBox2").val() + '&box2=Box2&val2=' + allvs,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        Processbox(data); // This function displaying the result.
    }
});
```

In my java code i am retrieving all these parameters and manipulating the Hashmap according to the values received.

```
public PortalURI execute(PortalContext portalContext) throws ActionException {

    HttpServletRequest request = portalContext.getPortalRequest().getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = portalContext.getPortalResponse().getResponse();
    HttpSession session = portalContext.getPortalRequest().getSession();

    Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapLeftBOX = new HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>();
    Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapRightBOX = new HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>();

    if ("add".equalsIgnoreCase(tick)) { 

       mapLeftBOX = (Map<String, List<List<String>>>) session.getAttribute(session,"mapLeft", null);   // retrieving the map Left value stored in session  in previous servlet
       mapLeftBOX.put(newkeyfromjquery, newvaluesfromjquery); // updsating the map with new values from jquery

       session.setAttribute("mapLeft", mapLeftBOX); // setting the new map in session

       out.write("concatStringsfrom mapLeftBOX"); // retrieve string values from map and write the response back to jquery
    }
}
```

This is my sample code. so, when a request will be fired jquery will get call and my servlet will get executed. The hashmap in the servlet will get updated according to the request parameter sent from jquery and once updated i have set the new map into the session and than send the response back to jquery which will display the result on jsp.

Now user will fire another request , and servlet will be called again, this time it will first get map from the session which ( i set in earlier request ) and than update that map with new jquery values and put it again in the session and send the response back to jquery and display in jsp.

This user may repeat number of times until he is done. once he is done , the jsp has the submit button on click of which user will be displayed the final results on another jsp by the same updated map . and finally user will click on submit on that jsp and store the values in server.

My question is :

As you have seen by now that i am calling and manipulating the java objects (hashmap) directly by Jquery get request. 
Is this the right approach i am following ? Let me tell you that my functionality is working fine in dev environment but i am worried with the approach before it goes live.

( another approach2-- which i thought of was that i could bring all the data first into the browser and than with jquery i could manipulate the DOM data and hence no need to call the Java servlet again and again. BUt my data is very complex , updating that in dom / client side would be very complex and even if i update that than i need to send the complete updated data of DOM to servlet which would be complex)

thats why i decided to go with the first approach, which will update my object directly in servlet and i can get the latest object from session to submit to the server.

Comment: I understood the context, but I'm not a big fan of your approach.. i.e. changing the session value via ajax. Can you give some more info? How does jquery get these values? Is it like an add button that add dynamic input fields or table cloumns?

Comment: @Syam Firstly Thanks for the response...actually when response come from servlet in jquery , i display the results. I have used checkboxes for each row , so the number of rows are checked to move the rows to the right box by clicking on Arrow >> . On click event is used for jquery GET request which sends the parameter of checked boxes in array.

Comment: so you are right they are table columns with checkboxes

Comment: Can you post the jsp snippet? the Checkbox part. But on a quick note I would suggest to make a single submit with all values. If you are using html form objects then you could use request.getParameterValues or request.getParameter to retrieve those values.

Comment: not sure if you got my scenerio properly ...that is >> button which calls the Servlet by jqueryGet request on click . i retrieve all the values using getParameter only and than only i update those in Java Map . after user finish clicking on arrow button and get the final response than i have a single submit button in my jsp which will than update the map values to the server